# Google Cloud platform performance: how many users

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

I have been trying to determine what instances I should choose, for Compute engine and Cloud SQL, for when we lunch our product.

Initially I'm working on handling max 500 users per day, with peak traffic likely to occur during the evenings. The users are expected to stay on the site with constant interactions for a lengthily period of time (10min+).

So far my guess's lead me to the following:

Compute engine: 
n1-standard-2 ->

2 virtuals cpu's, 3.75GB memory

Cloud SQL:
D2 ->

1GB ram, max 250 concurrent users

---

Am I in the right ball park, or can I use smaller/larger instances?

Comment: what machine type did you use?

Comment: @JohnBalvinArias sorry it was so long ago, I have no idea - also likely to have changed names by now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say to use appropriate [performance testing tools](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/performance.php) to simulate the traffic that will be hitting your server and estimate the amount of the resources you will require to handle the requests.

For Compute Engine VM instance, you can go with a lighter [machine type](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types) and take advantage of the GCE [Autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/) to automatically add more resources to your front-end when the traffic goes high.

I recommend watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TfbEwfYjKl4).

Comment: I was wondering if Google's Computer Engine is billed per user?